# Generating randomized questionnaires with Rmarkdown/knitr

Tags: r, random, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to produce randomized questionnaires using Rmarkdown and knitr.
However each time I run the script I get exactly the same result.

This is the code I'm using.

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,cache=FALSE}
    print(sample(1:10))
```
````

Is there a way of getting always a different result? It seems that the random seed is fixed and that it does not change at each line.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. I get different results every time. Did you set the seed somewhere in your script?

Comment: IF it's not a `set.seed` problem, perhaps it is how you are running your script, e.g. sometimes I knit from .rmd to .md and then forget to convert the .md from .html, and then I'm refreshing the HTML madly saying "it didn't update!"

Comment: I was able to solve it by first writing a file with 100 random number in it and then manually resetting the seed form the file each time. It's not very elegant but it did the job.